# Как можно в videoView смотреть трансляцию с twitch?

Tags: android

Как сделать показ трансляции в twitch в `VideoView` в `android`?

Если нельзя сделать в `VideoView` как это вообще можно сделать?

Comment: Twitch это большой сервис со своими серверами/аутентификацией апи и прочим. Так что вам надо идти на  https://dev.twitch.tv/ Там есть API для андроида

Comment: @SviatVolkov а нет возможности просто вставлять ссылку на трансляцию??

Comment: не знаю. вряд ли. мб через webview показывать страничку браузера с трансляцией